# How to fix default tab key navigation in Extjs 5.1?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5, keyboard-navigation

Currently I'm working on a code migration from ExtJS 4.2 to ExtJS 5.1. And I noticed MANY changes on default behavior of many components.

One of the things I noticed is that the default tab key navigation between components has changed and in this case is not quite predictable.

To reproduce go to the [4.2 fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13oj), and then click on the first text field, hit tab and then it would change focus to state combo box; hit tab again and it would go to "Next" button, hit tab again and it would go to "Second option" radio button, and so on in a predictable order.

Then repeat the same thing on [5.1 fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13oi). First thing you'll notice is that "My First Option" radio is unchecked (that's another issue), but the main issue I would like to fix is the odd order it follows on tab key press.

How can I make tab key navigation behave as it did on 4.2 version?

Including sample code here:

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    ]
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'My Navigable Panel',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'radiogroup',
                    layout: 'vbox',                    
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'radiofield',
                            boxLabel: 'My First Option',
                            name: 'radio',                            
                            value: true,
                            checked: true,
                            listeners: {
                                change: function(group, newValue, oldValue) {

                                    if(newValue) {
                                        group.up('form').down('fieldcontainer[name=containerA]').show();
                                        group.up('form').down('fieldcontainer[name=containerB]').hide();
                                    } else {
                                        group.up('form').down('fieldcontainer[name=containerA]').hide();
                                        group.up('form').down('fieldcontainer[name=containerB]').show();                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            name: 'containerA',                            
                            fieldDefaults: {
                                labelAlign: 'top',
                                margin: '0 5 0 5'
                            },
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'First field',
                                    allowBlank: false
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'combo',
                                    fieldLabel: 'State',
                                    width: 50,
                                    store : states,
                                    queryMode: 'local',
                                    displayField: 'name',
                                    valueField: 'abbr',
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    text: 'Next'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'radiofield',
                            boxLabel: 'My Second Option',
                            name: 'radio',
                            value: false
                        }
                    ]

                },
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    padding: '0 0 0 25',
                    name: 'containerB',
                    hidden: true,
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'radiogroup',
                        layout: 'vbox',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'radiofield',
                                fieldLabel: 'My nested radio button A',
                                name: 'subradio'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'radiofield',
                                fieldLabel: 'My nested radio button B',
                                name: 'subradio'
                            }
                        ]
                    }]
                }
            ],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        }).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did not find a way to tell ExtJS 5.1 to navigate through the form as it did on 4.2, but I managed to get the desired behavior by modifying my form composition (although it looks the same) in a way that ExtJS 5.1 was able to orderly follow.

To make that happen I removed the `radiogroup` component but kept all that was inside of it (which was pretty much the whole form content). It seems that structure didn't feel quite natural to the updated framework.

[Here is a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13r0) with the mentioned changes.

Including code here:

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    ]
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'My Navigable Panel',  
            items: [

                {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    boxLabel: 'My First Option',
                    name: 'radio',
                    value: true,
                    checked: true,
                    listeners: {
                        change: function(group, newValue, oldValue) {

                            if(newValue) {
                                group.up('form').down('fieldcontainer[name=containerA]').show();
                                group.up('form').down('fieldcontainer[name=containerB]').hide();
                            } else {
                                group.up('form').down('fieldcontainer[name=containerA]').hide();
                                group.up('form').down('fieldcontainer[name=containerB]').show();                                        
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    name: 'containerA',                            
                    fieldDefaults: {
                        labelAlign: 'top',
                        margin: '0 5 0 5'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'First field',
                            allowBlank: false
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'combo',
                            fieldLabel: 'State',
                            width: 50,
                            store : states,
                            queryMode: 'local',
                            displayField: 'name',
                            valueField: 'abbr',
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Next'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    boxLabel: 'My Second Option',
                    name: 'radio',
                    value: false                    
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    padding: '0 0 0 25',
                    name: 'containerB',
                    hidden: true,
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'radiogroup',
                        layout: 'vbox',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'radiofield',
                                fieldLabel: 'My nested radio button A',
                                name: 'subradio'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'radiofield',
                                fieldLabel: 'My nested radio button B',
                                name: 'subradio'
                            }
                        ]
                    }]
                }
            ],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        }).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't consider this as an exact answer, since what I really wanted was to somehow adjust navigation order, not being forced to change the composition of my view. But I'm including this answer because it is what I used at the end to solve the problem. If in a couple more days no one answers with a more satisfying answer, I'll mark this one as the right answer.